# How can I implement a 2 dimensional pointer array in my code to fulfill requirement?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I need help implementing a 2-dimensional pointer array to take care of the matrix. I'm not sure what the question means by that. Is it to perform calculations? I have done the rest and it runs without an error and returns the correct numbers. It's just this one part that I need help incorporating.

Problem: Create a script that will use Cramer’s rule to find the Solutions of Ax = b for A a 3 x 3 matrix and B a 3 x 1 matrix. (Pseudo Code Required)

Conditions you need to use

1. User defined functions that will return value and take arguments.
2. Also, this script should use two dimensional pointer that will take care of the whole matrix.

[Cramer's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule)

Please refer to the attached picture

[image: Picture of Problem]

```
#include<stdio.h>


//function for finding the determinants of the four matrices D, D1, D2 and D3 that will be created
//A 3*3 matrix will be passed to the function and the determinant is returned

double Determinant(double matx[3][3]){
    double determ;
    determ = (matx[0][0] * (matx[1][1] * matx[2][2] - matx[2][1] * matx[1][2])) - (matx[0][1] * (matx[1][0] * matx[2][2] - matx[1][2] * matx[2][0]))  + (matx[0][2] * (matx[1][0] * matx[2][1] - matx[1][1] * matx[2][0]));
    return determ;
}


//function for finding the solution using Cramer's rule
//we obtain the coefficients that are required to form the four matrices D, D1, D2 and D3
//then we apply Cramer's rule to find the solution

void Solution(double coefficients[3][4])
{
    //obtaining matrix D
    double D[3][3]= {
        { coefficients[0][0], coefficients[0][1], coefficients[0][2]},  //first row elements of D
        { coefficients[1][0], coefficients[1][1], coefficients[1][2] },  //second row elements of D
        { coefficients[2][0], coefficients[2][1], coefficients[2][2] }, //third row element of D
    };

    //Obtaining matrix D1
    double D1[3][3] = {
        { coefficients[0][3], coefficients[0][1], coefficients[0][2] }, //first row elements of D1
        { coefficients[1][3], coefficients[1][1], coefficients[1][2] }, //second row elements of D1
        { coefficients[2][3], coefficients[2][1], coefficients[2][2] }, //third row elements of D1
    };
    //Obtaining Matrix D2
    double D2[3][3] = {
        { coefficients[0][0], coefficients[0][3], coefficients[0][2] }, //first row elements of D2
        { coefficients[1][0], coefficients[1][3], coefficients[1][2] }, //second roe elements of D2
        { coefficients[2][0], coefficients[2][3], coefficients[2][2] }, //third row elements of D2
    };
    // Obtaining Matrix D3
    double D3[3][3] = {
        { coefficients[0][0], coefficients[0][1], coefficients[0][3] }, //first row elements of D3
        { coefficients[1][0], coefficients[1][1], coefficients[1][3] }, //second row elements of D3
        { coefficients[2][0], coefficients[2][1], coefficients[2][3] },  //third row elements of D3
    };

    //calling function Determinant() for calculating the determinants of matrices D, D1, D2 and D3

    double DD= Determinant(D);  //DD means determinant of D
    double DD1=Determinant(D1);  //DD1 means determinant of D1
    double DD2=Determinant(D2); //DD2 means determinant of D2
    double DD3=Determinant(D3); //DD3 means determinant of D3

    printf("DD is : %lf \n", DD);
    printf("DD1 is : %lf \n", DD1);
    printf("DD2 is : %lf \n", DD2);
    printf("DD3 is : %lf \n", DD3);

    //Cases for checking whether the system has a unique solution

    //Case 1
    if(DD!=0)
    {
        //we have a unique solution
        //apply Cramer's rule
        double x=DD1/DD;   //finding value of x using Cramer's rule
        double y=DD2/DD;   //finding value of y using Cramer's rule
        double z=DD3/DD;  //finding value of z using Cramer's rule

        printf("x is : %lf\n", x);
        printf("y is : %lf\n", y);
        printf("z is : %lf\n", z);
    }
    //Case 2

    else
    {
        if(DD1 == 0 && DD2 == 0 && DD3 == 0)   //infinite solutions
            printf("There are infinite solutions\n");
        else if (DD1 != 0 || DD2 != 0 || DD3 != 0)   //no solution
            printf("There is no solution\n");
    }
}

//main function for accepting coefficients from the user

int  main()
{
    int i, j;
    //example input
    //coefficient matrix in the form (a1, b1 ,c1 ,d1), (a2, b2, c2, d2), (a3, b3, c3, d3)
    double coeffs[3][4];

    printf("Enter the coeeficients\n");
    /*double coeffs[3][4] = {
     { 2, -1, 3, 9 },
     { 1, 1, 1, 6 },
     { 1, -1, 1, 2 },
     };
     */

    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<=3;j++)
            scanf("%lf",&coeffs[i][j]);
    }
    //call function Solution() and pass matrix coeffs as argument
    Solution(coeffs);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what "*two dimensional pointer*" is supposed to mean either.

Comment: @melpomene I struggled a while as well. I came to the conclusion: This addresses the matrices for determinant calculations. Instead, of copying matrix values (as Melissa did), you could use addresses to the original elements. (I'm about to write an answer.)

Comment: regarding: `if(DD1 == 0 && DD2 == 0 && DD3 == 0)   //infinite solutions
            printf("There are infinite solutions\n");
        else if (DD1 != 0 || DD2 != 0 || DD3 != 0)`   in the `else if()` There is no need for the `if()` part of the `else if()`  as the parameter is only an inversion of the prior `if()`

Answer (score 1):

> 2) Also, this script should use two dimensional pointer that will take care of the whole matrix.

I struggled a while to imagine how a 2D array of pointers (an array of arrays of pointers) could make sense in any way. Then, I noticed the sub-matrices which are used for determinant calculations. OP made local arrays, copying the values of the original 3×4 matrix. (I must admit I had done this exactly this way in her place.)

However, of course, the `Determinant()` function could be changed to work on a 3×3 array of pointers to `double`s. Instead, of passing values, the pointers (into original matrix) are passed.

After having checked that OP's sample code works, I did the following changes:

1. Signature of `Determinant()` changed to:

```
double Determinant(double *matx[3][3])
```

2. Access to `matx` in `Determinant()` adjusted: It has to be `*matx[][]` now:

```
    determ
      = (*matx[0][0] * (*matx[1][1] * *matx[2][2] - *matx[2][1] * *matx[1][2]))
      - (*matx[0][1] * (*matx[1][0] * *matx[2][2] - *matx[1][2] * *matx[2][0]))
      + (*matx[0][2] * (*matx[1][0] * *matx[2][1] - *matx[1][1] * *matx[2][0]));
```

3. Local arrays in `Solution()` respectively adjusted:

```
    //obtaining matrix D
    double *D[3][3]= {
        { &coefficients[0][0], &coefficients[0][1], &coefficients[0][2]},  //first row elements of D
        { &coefficients[1][0], &coefficients[1][1], &coefficients[1][2] },  //second row elements of D
        { &coefficients[2][0], &coefficients[2][1], &coefficients[2][2] }, //third row element of D
    };

    //Obtaining matrix D1
    double *D1[3][3] = {
        { &coefficients[0][3], &coefficients[0][1], &coefficients[0][2] }, //first row elements of D1
        { &coefficients[1][3], &coefficients[1][1], &coefficients[1][2] }, //second row elements of D1
        { &coefficients[2][3], &coefficients[2][1], &coefficients[2][2] }, //third row elements of D1
    };
    //Obtaining Matrix D2
    double *D2[3][3] = {
        { &coefficients[0][0], &coefficients[0][3], &coefficients[0][2] }, //first row elements of D2
        { &coefficients[1][0], &coefficients[1][3], &coefficients[1][2] }, //second roe elements of D2
        { &coefficients[2][0], &coefficients[2][3], &coefficients[2][2] }, //third row elements of D2
    };
    // Obtaining Matrix D3
    double *D3[3][3] = {
        { &coefficients[0][0], &coefficients[0][1], &coefficients[0][3] }, //first row elements of D3
        { &coefficients[1][0], &coefficients[1][1], &coefficients[1][3] }, //second row elements of D3
        { &coefficients[2][0], &coefficients[2][1], &coefficients[2][3] },  //third row elements of D3
    };
```

The complete sample:

```
#include<stdio.h>

//function for finding the determinants of the four matrices D, D1, D2 and D3 that will be created
//A 3*3 matrix will be passed to the function and the determinant is returned

double Determinant(double *matx[3][3]){
    double determ;
    determ
      = (*matx[0][0] * (*matx[1][1] * *matx[2][2] - *matx[2][1] * *matx[1][2]))
      - (*matx[0][1] * (*matx[1][0] * *matx[2][2] - *matx[1][2] * *matx[2][0]))
      + (*matx[0][2] * (*matx[1][0] * *matx[2][1] - *matx[1][1] * *matx[2][0]));
    return determ;
}


//function for finding the solution using Cramer's rule
//we obtain the coefficients that are required to form the four matrices D, D1, D2 and D3
//then we apply Cramer's rule to find the solution

void Solution(double coefficients[3][4])
{
    //obtaining matrix D
    double *D[3][3]= {
        { &coefficients[0][0], &coefficients[0][1], &coefficients[0][2]},  //first row elements of D
        { &coefficients[1][0], &coefficients[1][1], &coefficients[1][2] },  //second row elements of D
        { &coefficients[2][0], &coefficients[2][1], &coefficients[2][2] }, //third row element of D
    };

    //Obtaining matrix D1
    double *D1[3][3] = {
        { &coefficients[0][3], &coefficients[0][1], &coefficients[0][2] }, //first row elements of D1
        { &coefficients[1][3], &coefficients[1][1], &coefficients[1][2] }, //second row elements of D1
        { &coefficients[2][3], &coefficients[2][1], &coefficients[2][2] }, //third row elements of D1
    };
    //Obtaining Matrix D2
    double *D2[3][3] = {
        { &coefficients[0][0], &coefficients[0][3], &coefficients[0][2] }, //first row elements of D2
        { &coefficients[1][0], &coefficients[1][3], &coefficients[1][2] }, //second roe elements of D2
        { &coefficients[2][0], &coefficients[2][3], &coefficients[2][2] }, //third row elements of D2
    };
    // Obtaining Matrix D3
    double *D3[3][3] = {
        { &coefficients[0][0], &coefficients[0][1], &coefficients[0][3] }, //first row elements of D3
        { &coefficients[1][0], &coefficients[1][1], &coefficients[1][3] }, //second row elements of D3
        { &coefficients[2][0], &coefficients[2][1], &coefficients[2][3] },  //third row elements of D3
    };

    //calling function Determinant() for calculating the determinants of matrices D, D1, D2 and D3

    double DD= Determinant(D);  //DD means determinant of D
    double DD1=Determinant(D1);  //DD1 means determinant of D1
    double DD2=Determinant(D2); //DD2 means determinant of D2
    double DD3=Determinant(D3); //DD3 means determinant of D3

    printf("DD is : %lf \n", DD);
    printf("DD1 is : %lf \n", DD1);
    printf("DD2 is : %lf \n", DD2);
    printf("DD3 is : %lf \n", DD3);

    //Cases for checking whether the system has a unique solution

    //Case 1
    if(DD!=0)
    {
        //we have a unique solution
        //apply Cramer's rule
        double x=DD1/DD;   //finding value of x using Cramer's rule
        double y=DD2/DD;   //finding value of y using Cramer's rule
        double z=DD3/DD;  //finding value of z using Cramer's rule

        printf("x is : %lf\n", x);
        printf("y is : %lf\n", y);
        printf("z is : %lf\n", z);
    }
    //Case 2

    else
    {
        if(DD1 == 0 && DD2 == 0 && DD3 == 0)   //infinite solutions
            printf("There are infinite solutions\n");
        else if (DD1 != 0 || DD2 != 0 || DD3 != 0)   //no solution
            printf("There is no solution\n");
    }
}

//main function for accepting coefficients from the user

int  main()
{
#ifdef TEST
    //example input
    double coeffs[3][4] = {
     { 3, -2, 1, 6 },
     { 1,  1, 2, 7 },
     { 1,  1, 0, 5 },
    };
#else // (not) TEST
    //coefficient matrix in the form (a1, b1 ,c1 ,d1), (a2, b2, c2, d2), (a3, b3, c3, d3)
    double coeffs[3][4];
    printf("Enter the coefficients\n");
    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<=3;j++)
            scanf("%lf",&coeffs[i][j]);
    }
#endif // TEST
    //call function Solution() and pass matrix coeffs as argument
    Solution(coeffs);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
DD is : -10.000000 
DD1 is : -30.000000 
DD2 is : -20.000000 
DD3 is : -10.000000 
x is : 3.000000
y is : 2.000000
z is : 1.000000
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03314dd79347aca7)</kbd>

(Please, note the `-DTEST` in compile line to force use of sample data.)

---

I'm still not sure how the usage of pointers instead of values may be an improvement. On the first glance, one may think: 'Hey, all the copying has been prevented.' But I don't expect much improvement by this:

1. Replacing `double` by `double*` doesn't save any space on a 64 bit platform because `sizeof (double)`: 8 and `sizeof (double*)`: 8 as well.
2. The "saved memory" is allocated on stack. So, it's non-permanent and nothing which must be saved (as long as there isn't the danger of stack overflow).
3. Providing a data in contiguous memory (by copying values) may improve cache locality when this data is accessed. So, it might be worth to have extra copies.
4. The use of pointers causes another indirection for each access which probably costs some extra cycles.

As this seems to be an assignment, I assume, it's intended just for teaching the technique of indirect access…